# spring data redis master slave config

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

Following is my jedis config

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory getJedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getRedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

This config works well when I have single server. What I want to do is have 1 redis master and multiple redis slaves. Per redis documentation, read should happen from slaves, and write should happen from master. How do I change above configuration to use master for writing and slave for reading?

Lets say that my master is at 192.168.10.10 and slave is at localhost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

At this time there's no configuration option in Spring Data Redis that would enable the desired behaviour. Nor does *Jedis* iteself offer support for this kind of scenario (see [jedis #458](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/458)).
`RedisConnection` requests a connection from the factory when executing operations. At this point the usage purpose of the resource requested it is not clear as the command could be `r`, `w` or `rw`.

One potential solution would be a custom `RedisConnectionFactory` capable of providing the connection - to one of the slaves you have - in case of a readonly command being executed.

```java
SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory factory = new SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory();
factory.afterPropertiesSet();

RedisConnection connection = factory.getConnection();

// writes to master
connection.set("foo".getBytes(), "bar".getBytes());

// reads from slave
connection.get("foo".getBytes());

/**
 * SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory wraps JedisConnection with a proy that delegates readonly commands to slaves.
 */
class SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory extends JedisConnectionFactory {

  /**
    * Get a proxied connection to Redis capable of sending
    * readonly commands to a slave node
    */
  public JedisConnection getConnection() {

    JedisConnection c = super.getConnection();

    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(c);
    proxyFactory.addAdvice(new ConnectionSplittingInterceptor(this));
    proxyFactory.setProxyTargetClass(true);

    return JedisConnection.class.cast(proxyFactory.getProxy());
  };

  /**
   * This one will get the connection to one of the slaves to read from there
   * 
   * @return
   */
  public RedisConnection getSlaveConnection() {

    //TODO: find the an available slave serving the data
    return new JedisConnection(new Jedis("your slave host lookup here"));
  }

  static class ConnectionSplittingInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor,
      org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor {

    private final SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory factory;

    public ConnectionSplittingInterceptor(SlaveAwareJedisConnectionFactory factory) {
      this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {

      RedisCommand commandToExecute = RedisCommand.failsafeCommandLookup(method.getName());

      if (!commandToExecute.isReadonly()) {
        return invoke(method, obj, args);
      }

      RedisConnection connection = factory.getSlaveConnection();

      try {
        return invoke(method, connection, args);
      } finally {
        // properly close the connection after executing command
        if (!connection.isClosed()) {
          connection.close();
        }
      }
    }

    private Object invoke(Method method, Object target, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

      try {
        return method.invoke(target, args);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      return intercept(invocation.getThis(), invocation.getMethod(), invocation.getArguments(), null);
    }
  }
}
```

There solution above holds serveral issues. Eg.  `MULTI` `EXEC` blocks in you application might no longer work as expected since commands now potentially get piped somewhere you do not want them to be. So maybe it would also make sense to have multiple `RedisTemplates` for dedicated *read*, *write* purpose.

Comment: how about two two jedis connection factories and two redis templates, one for read and the other for write? Will that work (in theory) ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) to keep master/slave configuration of redis...you can use below to connect to sentinel pool-

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration() .master("mymaster")
    .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26379) .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26380);
return new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
}
```

reference: [Spring Sentinel support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel)

Comment: using Redis Sentinel support alone, you get fail-over when sentinal promotes a new node to master, but you don't get load-balancing, everything still goes to master.

Answer (score 2):

You want [write-to-master-read-from-slave](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:write-to-master-read-from-replica)

This is how to configure it with a sentinal cluster and spring-boot

```
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      sentinel: 
        master: mymaster
        nodes: my.sentinel.hostname1:26379,my.sentinel.hostname2:26379
      port: 6379
```

And spring config

```
@Configuration
public class RedisDatasourceConfig {

  @Bean
  public LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer lettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer() {
    return p -> p.readFrom(SLAVE_PREFERRED);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replication with master/slave architecture is different from Sentinel.

Setting redis read replicas are very easy.

My spring boot application yaml.

```
redis:
  master:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  slaves:
    - host: localhost
      port: 16379
    - host: localhost
      port: 26379
```

For the above instances, slaves instances redis config should be updated as shown below.

```
################################# REPLICATION #################################

# Master-Replica replication. Use replicaof to make a Redis instance a copy of
# another Redis server. A few things to understand ASAP about Redis replication.
#
#   +------------------+      +---------------+
#   |      Master      | ---> |    Replica    |
#   | (receive writes) |      |  (exact copy) |
#   +------------------+      +---------------+
#
# 1) Redis replication is asynchronous, but you can configure a master to
#    stop accepting writes if it appears to be not connected with at least
#    a given number of replicas.
# 2) Redis replicas are able to perform a partial resynchronization with the
#    master if the replication link is lost for a relatively small amount of
#    time. You may want to configure the replication backlog size (see the next
#    sections of this file) with a sensible value depending on your needs.
# 3) Replication is automatic and does not need user intervention. After a
#    network partition replicas automatically try to reconnect to masters
#    and resynchronize with them.
#
replicaof master 6379
```

Check here for a docker set up.

https://www.vinsguru.com/redis-master-slave-with-spring-boot/