# Spring data redis master and slave configuration in application-context.xml

Tags: xml, applicationcontext, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have done a poc on spring data redis by using jedis connection factory and redis template which is working fine and getting results fast with single node, but now i want to use master to write and child for read to improve reading performance so can any one help me to configure these information in applicationcontext.xml.

Comment: Could you provide the code you already wrote ?

Comment: There is actually now configuration option for master/write slave/read available for spring-data-redis. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527738/spring-data-redis-master-slave-config. If you want to join the discussion, there's an issue for that open in [mp911de/lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/issues/114).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Hi I have intergrate sentinal configuration in spring data redis with below code